# is there any elegant method to decrease Eloquent(with method) level in laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

TestController.php

```
    $result = GoodsSku::with(['media' => function ($query) {
        $query->select('media_resource.id', 'media_resource.full_path');
    }])->whereIn('id', [28])->get();
    dd($result);
```

Here is the content of $result

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:22 [▼
    "id" => 28
    "goods_id" => 14
    "title" => phone
    "has_cover" => array:7 [▼
      "id" => 289
      "media_id" => 289
      "entity_id" => 28
      "media" => array:20 [▼
        "id" => 289
        "path" => "2015/11/08/fd1bf228_pic_show01.jpg"
        "full_path" => "http://example.com/2015/11/08/fd1bf228_pic_show01.jpg"
        "extension" => "jpg"
        "deleted_at" => null
      ]
    ]
    "goods" => array:7 [▼
      "id" => 289
      "title" => phone goods
      "goods_sku_id" => 28
      "category_id" => 3
      "category" => array:20 [▼
        "id" => 3
        "name" => "mobile"
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

Usually,i get the full_path through `$result->has_cover->media->fullpath`

i want to get the category name have to through `$result->goods->category->name`.

You know,this is not friendly to front-end developer(FE).

The more relationships,the more troubles to FE

Is there any elegant method to make this $result friendly to FE use Eloquent(With method)?

Maybe like this `$result->full_path` or `$result->media.full_path`

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please show me your models

Comment: I think you should use `hasManyThrough` relation.

Comment: probably `$result->fetch('has_cover.media.full_path')`.